# How can I create a like-a-template function which takes a bunch of code as an argument?

Tags: python

I want to create a function which takes a bunch of code as so-called "argument", so that I can implement any block-of-code I want later on.
Here is a sample:

```
def loop(c):
  while c != (1 or 0):
    try:
      c = int(input("Choice? (1/2) - "))
    except ValueError:
      print("Enter a valid value.")
    else:
      if c == 1:
        # i want to have different implementations of loop(c) by writing any (bunch of) statements i want here.
      elif c == 0:
        print("Goodbye...")
      else:
        print("Please enter either 1 or 0.")
```

What I basically want to do is to create a template so that I can use this code snippet with if block (where the comment-line is) is filled (replaced) with anything I want. How can I do it?

Comment: You could pass an extra parameter to decide which code to implement in your if statement, is that something your looking for or are you looking for a class based method of implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accept functions as arguments:

```
def loop(c, func):
  while c != (1 or 0):
    try:
      c = int(input("Choice? (1/2) - "))
    except ValueError:
      print("Enter a valid value.")
    else:
      if c == 1:
        func()
      elif c == 0:
        print("Goodbye...")
      else:
        print("Please enter either 1 or 0.")
```

An example of calling it would be one of these:

```
def a():
    # whatever code you want here
    print('in the function')

loop(c, a)
```

Or even simpler (for simple functions):

```
loop(c, lambda: print('in a lambda'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callable (function or lambda) to your function as an argument.

```
def perform_function(func):
    if input() == "foo":
        func()

perform_function(lambda: print("Hello World"))
```